# Orienteering Problem with a graph that both nodes and edges are weighted

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

Sorry I know little about graph theory and wonder if there exist this kind of theoretic problems. It may relates to orienteering problem.

Giving an undirected graph G(V,E) that with scores on both V and E, a start node and an end node, the problem is to find a path from the start to the end that maximize total scores on both nodes and edges which may subject to some constraints(i.e. time, length). There is no need to guarantee that it have to be the shortest path.

I want to know the formal definition of these problem and related papers.

Can any of you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: The problem is very general and hard even without constraints. Indeed, if all vertices have positive score and all edges have zero score then even to decide whether there exists a path whose total score is the sum of all vertex score is a Hamiltonian path problem, which is known to be $NP$-hard [Karp, 1972]. On the other hand, if all vertices have a constant score $s_v$, all edges have a constant score $s_e$, and 
$s_v+s_e <0$ then the problem to find a path with a maximum total score is the shortest path problem, which, I guess is solvable in polynomial time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It doesn't matter that the problem is solvable in polynomial time since original orienteering problem is already NP-hard. What I want to know is that if there are some related papers and any approximate algorithms.